# No library stub file for module lxml.html in python

Tags: python

Upon adding this line `import lxml.html` vim displays `No library stub file for module lxml.html`.

What does it mean?

Answer (score 4):

Mypy makes use of a package called TypeShed. Typeshed contains type stubs for the python standard library and a few third party packages. lxml isn't represented there. So the type checker doesn't know about the types within lxml.

Stubs are explained here: https://github.com/python/mypy/wiki/Creating-Stubs-For-Python-Modules

Comment: Any insights on how to avoid or solve this on developers' end ?

Comment: @AnshumanTiwari to ignore the warning, add this to your `mypy.ini`:
`[mypy-lxml.html.*]
ignore_missing_imports = True`

Answer (score 2):

The stub file for `lxml.html` [was not available until version 0.2.0](https://github.com/lxml/lxml-stubs/issues/15) (released in May 2021). You can just `pip install lxml-stubs --upgrade`.

Answer (score 0):

For late comers, I have [released `types-lxml`](https://github.com/abelcheung/types-lxml) which is now feature complete and completely supersedes `lxml-stubs`. If anything is missing or doesn't work as intended, it is welcome to [file bug report](https://github.com/abelcheung/types-lxml/issues)!